# Maxmind Free GeoIPCity.dat return empty State & City for most of the IPs.

Tags: state, geoip, maxmind, city

I have updated my PHP API & database today (26/03/2014) and still not getting the state & city for few of the IPs.

Here are the IPs for your reference:
120.62.2.24, 103.2.133.154, 120.57.144.226, 59.96.210.147, 117.223.148.132

But when I check in maxmind demo page, all the details are getting displayed for the above IPs.

If anyone help me out in this would be great.

Comment: It is likely that the GeoLite just doesn't have city-level data for those IPs. The website demo is for the paid web service.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can consider [IP2Location LITE](http://lite.ip2location.com/) database to examine the IPs. It is free with zipcode and time zone data as well.